# how to move button inline with horizontal checklist?

Tags: css

I have the following code for creating a horizontal checklist and a submit button: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mkynpvt/)

I would like for the submit button to show up inline with the checklist, right after "Visual Title". How can I achieve this? I've tried `display: inline-block`, `display: inline`, `display: flex`, but none of it works.

```css
.widget-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.checkbox-wrapper-htmlview {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0.3125em;
}

div button{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="widget-container">
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('heading', $event.target.checked)" />Heading</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('paragraph', $event.target.checked)" />Paragraph</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('unorderedlist', $event.target.checked)" />Unordered List</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('orderedlist', $event.target.checked)" />Ordered List</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('table', $event.target.checked)" />Table</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('visualtitle', $event.target.checked)" />Visual Title</label>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button>submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put the button in the same container, where the checkboxes are located. Otherwise you can't achieve this.

```css
.widget-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    /*justify-content: center;*/
}

.checkbox-wrapper-htmlview {
    padding: 0.5em;
    margin: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0;
    background-color: #f6f6f6;
    border-color: #ddd;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-radius: 0.3125em;
}

button{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0.5em 1em 0.5em 0;
}
```

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <div class="widget-container">
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('heading', $event.target.checked)" />Heading</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('paragraph', $event.target.checked)" />Paragraph</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('unorderedlist', $event.target.checked)" />Unordered List</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('orderedlist', $event.target.checked)" />Ordered List</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('table', $event.target.checked)" />Table</label>
      <label class="checkbox-wrapper-htmlview"><input type="checkbox" name="annotationtype" (change)="onChange('visualtitle', $event.target.checked)" />Visual Title</label>
      <button>submit</button>
    </div>
   
</form>
```

Comment: I agree to this solution, also in addition to OP the reason why it will never be in the same line because you have declared a <div> tag to your button. Div tags are block-level elements, which means it will always take the full width available, thus it pushes other block level elements to the next line.